# MS Access: Report SetProperty On Activate does not work, on batch print

Tags: ms-access

**VBA** Version

Report `On Activate` Event

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Report_Activate()
    If (Me.SomeTextBox = "SomeText25") Then
        Me.SomeLabel.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Macro** Version

Report `On Activate` Event

```
If [SomeTextBox]=SomeText25 Then
    SetPropery
        Control Name SomeLabel
            Property Visible
                Value False
End If
```

The Report Previews and Prints as desired, from Print Preview and Report View, as a single Report, but not when Printing multiple results programmatically, from the same Query Data.

`Query Criteria: Between...`

When the Report Prints multiple records, the control is visible on all Printed Reports, with the `On Activate` Event being ignored.

It's looking like I may have to `Loop` through the records set, to get the desired results.

As a work around, I converted the `Label` to a `TextBox`, and am using `Conditional Formatting`, to hide (White out), the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting my `If/Then`, in the `On Print` Event, of the Detail Section, with an `Else` to reset it, Prints all Reports correctly.

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)`
    If...Then
        ...Visible = False
    Else
        ...Visible = True
    End IF
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The *OnActivate* doesn't fire for normal printing, only for preview, so you will have to use another event.